# Closed Captions vs Transcripts of the video: Which one is better for SEO?

Tags: seo, video

I have a few videos I have transcribed. I'd like to know how I'd better include them in my blog posts. Should I caption them (e.g. in Youtube) or just include the transcript at the end of the post.

Which one is better SEO-wise?

Answer (score 3):

If you can, do both.

If you can only do one or the other, stick with the transcript - it's guaranteed to be readable, regardless of how advanced a particular bot happens to be.

Comment: That'll be great for deaf people trying to follow along the video while scanning a vertical column of text somewhere else on the page...

Comment: ... which they wouldn't have found unless the text had been there for the search engines to begin with ;)

Comment: That's why you need both. =P You can have both visibility _and_ accessibility/usability. Though for SEO, a short description of the video's content and a good, descriptive title is usually good enough. But for some content you'll want the full transcript anyway for those who can't play the video for some reason.

Comment: Which is why I stated "If you can, do both." - but, given that the question focused upon advice pertaining to SEO (and given that only a specialized search engine will read video captions) the full transcript is the optimal choice for addressing SEO concerns (don't know why captions would be impossible if one already has a full transcript already prepared, but that's another story).

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to do both. But if you don't have the time, you could always outsource the task to a professional transcription service, which is really affordable nowadays. There's a transcription service called DirectCaption.com which can get your transcription done at just $1 per minute. They also offer a variety of caption formats that you can export, so you won't to have to worry about uploading them in any website.